# Haskell - GHC error: Could not find module ‘Prelude’/ Perhaps you haven't installed the profiling libraries for package ‘base-4.12.0.0’?

Tags: ubuntu, haskell, compiler-errors, profiling, ghc

I've just installed `haskell-platform` from the Ubuntu repositories (it comes with `GHC` version `8.6.5`) [as instructed by the website](https://www.haskell.org/platform/#linux-ubuntu).
Now, upon trying to compile a program for profiling, using `ghc -O2 -prof myCode.hs`, I'm met with the following error message:

```
myCode.hs:1:1: error: 
    Could not find module ‘Prelude’
    Perhaps you haven't installed the profiling libraries for package ‘base-4.12.0.0’?
```

and similarly for the `System.IO` module.

Should they not come with the default Haskell instalation? How can I proceed?
Perhaps I should purge it all and get Haskell form another source (`Stack`, `Ghcup`, etc? Should it matter?)

I'm fairly new to this, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: my experience is that `ghcup` is very straightforward for beginners like myself. At least on linux. This is also what I see experienced people recommend.

Comment: For profiling it seems you need to install `haskell-platform-prof`, but I agree with user1984 that ghcup is probably a better way to install Haskell tools.

Comment: @Noughtmare that's indeed the case! Thank you very much, I completely missed this. Wouldn't you like to turn this into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu, essentially all of the Haskell packages come in bland and `-prof` flavors. You need the latter for profiling.

ghcup is also fine. There's no need to purge it all -- ghcup and the package manager can coexist cleanly.